# Obscure 80's cartoon: jungle tree house with a glass domed roof, characters going berserk after inhaling a vapour from a ring

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I remember seeing a cartoon as a kid that takes place in a jungle. I remember the characters travelling up an elevator in a tree up to a big tree house with a glass domed roof or something like that?

The bad guy had black hair and a black moustache and a pink shirt with black trousers. The good characters were a blonde lady wearing a yellow jumpsuit and a guy with a brown jacket and brown trousers.

Both the bad guy and the good guy inhaled a vapour from a ring which made them beast-like (hairy and muscular) and they both fought while the tree house was falling.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)